# Related accounts does not update avatar

Tags: support, gravatar, user-accounts

**Related accounts** in profiles of SO/SU/etc seems to not update the avatar picture.

I try cleaning cache, but I think is a server-side problem.

I don't know if it's a bug or designed behavior.

Comment: Your gravatars are all the same now though

Comment: I don't know, if I click here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52879?tab=accounts#sort-top the image is different

Comment: It can take over a day for both sizes of avatars to change...but they look the same for me.

Comment: This evening I tried from home, funny that here it is working. I think that at this point the problem is generated by my company's proxy, probably it creates a cache of some pages. Sorry for bother, I think that some one can close.

Comment: Closing by request as 'norepro'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just takes a little while. Have some faith/patience.

Also, make sure that your emails are the same on both accounts.  That is what Gravitar uses to update your avatar on these sites.

Comment: And clear your cache while you're at it.

Comment: Hold the power button down for 10 seconds.  Then unplug your computer for 30 min and let it rest for a bit.  Then start your computer up again.  Repeat this process at least 2 more times.  Then clear your cache, then try it.

Comment: i tried, same as before

Comment: Rubbing ice-cream on the keyboard sometimes works for me.